# jQuery Program Dynamically Loaded Events Aren't Being Detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-forms, formset

I am running a modified version of a formset script that was found in GITHUB.

```
;(function($) {
    $.fn.formset = function(opts)
    {
        var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.formset.defaults, opts),
            flatExtraClasses = options.extraClasses.join(' '),
            totalForms = $('#id_' + options.prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS'),
            initialForms = $('#id_' + options.prefix + '-INITIAL_FORMS'),
            currentFormIndex = parseInt(totalForms.val()),
            maxForms = $('#id_' + options.prefix + '-MAX_NUM_FORMS'),
            minForms = $('#id_' + options.prefix + '-MIN_NUM_FORMS'),
            childElementSelector = 'input,select,textarea,label,div',
            $$ = $(this),

            applyExtraClasses = function(row, ndx) {
                if (options.extraClasses) {
                    row.removeClass(flatExtraClasses);
                    row.addClass(options.extraClasses[ndx % options.extraClasses.length]);
                }
            },

            updateElementIndex = function(elem, prefix, ndx) {
                var idRegex = new RegExp(prefix + '-(\\d+|__prefix__)-'),
                    replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx + '-';
                if (elem.attr("for")) elem.attr("for", elem.attr("for").replace(idRegex, replacement));
                if (elem.attr('id')) elem.attr('id', elem.attr('id').replace(idRegex, replacement));
                if (elem.attr('name')) elem.attr('name', elem.attr('name').replace(idRegex, replacement));
            },

            hasChildElements = function(row) {
                return row.find(childElementSelector).length > 0;
            },

            showAddButton = function() {
                return maxForms.length == 0 ||
                    (maxForms.val() == '' || (maxForms.val() - totalForms.val() > 0));
            },

            showDeleteLinks = function() {
                return minForms.length == 0 ||
                    (minForms.val() == '' || (totalForms.val() - minForms.val() > 0));
            },

            insertDeleteLink = function(row) {
                var delCssSelector = $.trim(options.deleteCssClass).replace(/\s+/g, '.'),
                    addCssSelector = $.trim(options.addCssClass).replace(/\s+/g, '.');

                var delButtonHTML = document.createElement("a");
                    delButtonHTML.classList.add(options.deleteCssClass);
                    delButtonHTML.textContent = options.deleteText;
                    delButtonHTML.id = "deleteID";

                if (options.deleteContainerClass) {
                    row.find('[class*="' + options.deleteContainerClass + '"]').append(delButtonHTML);
                } else if (row.is('TR')) {
                    row.children(':last').append(delButtonHTML);
                } else if (row.is('UL') || row.is('OL')) {
                    row.append('<li>' + delButtonHTML + '</li>');
                } else {
                    row.append(delButtonHTML);
                }

                if (!showDeleteLinks()){
                    row.find('a.' + delCssSelector).hide();
                }

                row.find('a.' + delCssSelector).click(function() {
                var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete3?");
                if (result) {
                var row = $(this).parents('.dynamic-form');
                var itemIdInput = row.find('input:hidden[id $= "-id"]');
                var itemId = itemIdInput.val();
                var deleteInput = `<input type="hidden" name="line_items_to_delete" value="${itemId}">`;  // Update here....
                if( $(deleteInput).val() ) {
                  $('#line_items_to_delete').append(deleteInput);   // Update here....
                }

                var row = $(this).parents('.' + options.formCssClass),
                    del = row.find('input:hidden[id $= "-DELETE"]'),
                    buttonRow = row.siblings("a." + addCssSelector + ', .' + options.formCssClass + '-add'),
                    forms;
                if (del.length) {
                    del.val('on');
                    row.hide();
                    forms = $('.' + options.formCssClass);
                    totalForms.val(forms.length);
                } else {
                    row.remove();
                    forms = $('.' + options.formCssClass).not('.formset-custom-template');
                    totalForms.val(forms.length);
                }
                for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++) {
                    applyExtraClasses(forms.eq(i), i);
                    if (!del.length) {
                        forms.eq(i).find(childElementSelector).each(function() {
                            updateElementIndex($(this), options.prefix, i);
                        });
                    }
                }

                if (!showDeleteLinks()){
                    $('a.' + delCssSelector).each(function(){$(this).hide();});
                }
                if (buttonRow.is(':hidden') && showAddButton()) buttonRow.show();
                if (options.removed) options.removed(row);
                return false;
                }
              });
            };

        $$.each(function(i) {
            var row = $(this),
                del = row.find('input:checkbox[id $= "-DELETE"]');
            if (del.length) {
                if (del.is(':checked')) {
                    del.before('<input type="hidden" name="' + del.attr('name') +'" id="' + del.attr('id') +'" value="on" />');
                    row.hide();
                } else {
                    del.before('<input type="hidden" name="' + del.attr('name') +'" id="' + del.attr('id') +'" />');
                }
                $('label[for="' + del.attr('id') + '"]').hide();
                del.remove();
            }
            if (hasChildElements(row)) {
                row.addClass(options.formCssClass);
                if (row.is(':visible')) {
                    insertDeleteLink(row);
                    applyExtraClasses(row, i);
                }
            }
        });

        if ($$.length) {
            var hideAddButton = !showAddButton(),
                addButton, template;
            if (options.formTemplate) {
                template = (options.formTemplate instanceof $) ? options.formTemplate : $(options.formTemplate);
                template.removeAttr('id').addClass(options.formCssClass + ' formset-custom-template');
                template.find(childElementSelector).each(function() {
                    updateElementIndex($(this), options.prefix, '__prefix__');
                });
                insertDeleteLink(template);
            } else {
                if (options.hideLastAddForm) $('.' + options.formCssClass + ':last').hide();
                template = $('.' + options.formCssClass + ':last').clone(true).removeAttr('id');
                template.find('input:hidden[id $= "-DELETE"]').remove();
                template.find(childElementSelector).not(options.keepFieldValues).each(function() {
                    var elem = $(this);
                    if (elem.is('input:checkbox') || elem.is('input:radio')) {
                        elem.attr('checked', false);
                    }
                    if (elem.is('select')) {
                        elem.append('<option style="display:none" selected value="">Optional</option>');
                    }
                    else {
                        elem.val('');
                    }
                });
            }
            options.formTemplate = template;

            var addButtonHTML = '<a class="' + options.addCssClass + '" href="javascript:void(0)">' + options.addText + '</a>';
            if (options.addContainerClass) {
              var addContainer = $('[class*="' + options.addContainerClass + '"');
              addContainer.append(addButtonHTML);
              addButton = addContainer.find('[class="' + options.addCssClass + '"]');
            } else if ($$.is('TR')) {
                var numCols = $$.eq(0).children().length,
                    buttonRow = $('<tr><td colspan="' + numCols + '">' + addButtonHTML + '</tr>').addClass(options.formCssClass + '-add');
                $$.parent().append(buttonRow);
                addButton = buttonRow.find('a');
            } else {
                $$.filter(':last').after(addButtonHTML);
                addButton = $$.filter(':last').next();
            }

            if (hideAddButton) addButton.hide();

            addButton.click(function() {
              var formCount = currentFormIndex,
                    row = options.formTemplate.clone(true).removeClass('formset-custom-template'),
                    buttonRow = $($(this).parents('tr.' + options.formCssClass + '-add').get(0) || this),
                    delCssSelector = $.trim(options.deleteCssClass).replace(/\s+/g, '.');

                    let highestId = 0;
                    const idRegex = /\d+/;
                    $("input[name$='-research_line_item_description']").each(function(){  // Update here....
                      const currentName = $(this).attr('name');
                      const idVal = currentName.match(idRegex);
                      const idInt = parseInt(idVal);
                      highestId = Math.max(highestId,parseInt(idInt));
                    });
                    formCount = highestId+1;

                applyExtraClasses(row, formCount);
                row.insertBefore(buttonRow).show();
                row.find(childElementSelector).each(function() {
                    updateElementIndex($(this), options.prefix, formCount);
                });
                totalForms.val(formCount + 1);
                if (showDeleteLinks()){
                  $('a.' + delCssSelector).each(function(){$(this).show();});
                  RemoveFirstButton();
                  UpdatePlaceHolder();
                  UpdateTotals();
                 }
                if (!showAddButton()) buttonRow.hide();
                if (options.added) options.added(row);
                currentFormIndex++;
                return false;
            });
        }
        return $$;
    };

    /* Setup plugin defaults */
    $.fn.formset.defaults = {
        prefix: 'form',                         // The form prefix for your django formset
        formTemplate: null,                     // The jQuery selection cloned to generate new form instances
        addText: 'Add',                         // Text for the add link
        deleteText: 'Del',                      // Text for the delete link
        addContainerClass: null,                // Container CSS class for the add link
        deleteContainerClass: null,             // Container CSS class for the delete link
        addCssClass: 'add-row-budget',          // CSS class applied to the add link
        deleteCssClass: 'delete-row-budget',    // CSS class applied to the delete link
        formCssClass: 'dynamic-form',           // CSS class applied to each form in a formset
        extraClasses: [],                       // Additional CSS classes, which will be applied to each form in turn
        keepFieldValues: '',                    // jQuery selector for fields whose values should be kept when the form is cloned
        added: null,                            // Function called each time a new form is added
        removed: null,                          // Function called each time a form is deleted
        hideLastAddForm: false,                 // When set to true, hide last empty add form (becomes visible when clicking on add button)
    };
})(jQuery);
```

It works great!  With one exception....I am having trouble detecting when the buttons are clicked...If I do the following...

```
  $(".add-row-budget").on('click', function() {
     $(window).on('beforeunload',function(){
       return '';
     });
       console.log("test1");
  });
```

It doesn't work.  I kind of understand why...the elements are being loaded in dynamically...and from what I gather....They're not being bound...or I'm missing an Add-Event-Listener?  I've hacked this a bit...by adding...

```
RemoveFirstButton();
UpdatePlaceHolder();
UpdateTotals();
```

And this gets the code to "wakeup" and after the first pass I can get the...

```
  $(".add-row-budget").on('click', function() {
     $(window).on('beforeunload',function(){
       return '';
     });
       console.log("test1");
  });
```

To work.  How can I get the code above to work in concert with the original code in a less hacky way?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: @MykolaDekhtiarenko answer was correct, you need event delegation here.

Comment: @jcubic Thanks for the feedback but not in this case.  Because the formset function is being called, you need to include a call to another program which will essentially capture the events that are being created as a result of the formset function within the formset function.  I will show a final configuration in my answer.  I tested it and this solves my problem.  In a more straight forward architecture, event delegation would have worked.  Not in this case.

Comment: You have a jQuery plugin if you call `$(document).on('click', '.add-row-budget')` if call your plugin it will work until you remove the event. So your question and solution don't make sense.

Comment: @jcubic Thanks for the supportive and uplifting comment.  What I posted as an answer does work. and meets my needs  If you're suggesting there's a better way to craft a solution, I'm all ears.  The dynamically created events from the plugin are not being detected with my other code unless I make the changes that I've documented.

Answer (score 0):

```
;(function($) {
    $.fn.formset = function(opts)
    {
        var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.formset.defaults, opts),
            flatExtraClasses = options.extraClasses.join(' '),
            totalForms = $('#id_' + options.prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS'),
            initialForms = $('#id_' + options.prefix + '-INITIAL_FORMS'),
            currentFormIndex = parseInt(totalForms.val()),
            maxForms = $('#id_' + options.prefix + '-MAX_NUM_FORMS'),
            minForms = $('#id_' + options.prefix + '-MIN_NUM_FORMS'),
            childElementSelector = 'input,select,textarea,label,div',
            $$ = $(this),

            applyExtraClasses = function(row, ndx) {
                if (options.extraClasses) {
                    row.removeClass(flatExtraClasses);
                    row.addClass(options.extraClasses[ndx % options.extraClasses.length]);
                }
            },

            updateElementIndex = function(elem, prefix, ndx) {
                var idRegex = new RegExp(prefix + '-(\\d+|__prefix__)-'),
                    replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx + '-';
                if (elem.attr("for")) elem.attr("for", elem.attr("for").replace(idRegex, replacement));
                if (elem.attr('id')) elem.attr('id', elem.attr('id').replace(idRegex, replacement));
                if (elem.attr('name')) elem.attr('name', elem.attr('name').replace(idRegex, replacement));
            },

            hasChildElements = function(row) {
                return row.find(childElementSelector).length > 0;
            },

            showAddButton = function() {
                return maxForms.length == 0 ||
                    (maxForms.val() == '' || (maxForms.val() - totalForms.val() > 0));
            },

            showDeleteLinks = function() {
                return minForms.length == 0 ||
                    (minForms.val() == '' || (totalForms.val() - minForms.val() > 0));
            },

            insertDeleteLink = function(row) {
                var delCssSelector = $.trim(options.deleteCssClass).replace(/\s+/g, '.'),
                    addCssSelector = $.trim(options.addCssClass).replace(/\s+/g, '.');

                var delButtonHTML = document.createElement("a");
                    delButtonHTML.classList.add(options.deleteCssClass);
                    delButtonHTML.textContent = options.deleteText;
                    delButtonHTML.id = "deleteID";

                if (options.deleteContainerClass) {
                    row.find('[class*="' + options.deleteContainerClass + '"]').append(delButtonHTML);
                } else if (row.is('TR')) {
                    row.children(':last').append(delButtonHTML);
                } else if (row.is('UL') || row.is('OL')) {
                    row.append('<li>' + delButtonHTML + '</li>');
                } else {
                    row.append(delButtonHTML);
                }

                if (!showDeleteLinks()){
                    row.find('a.' + delCssSelector).hide();
                }

                row.find('a.' + delCssSelector).click(function() {
                var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete3?");
                if (result) {
                var row = $(this).parents('.dynamic-form');
                var itemIdInput = row.find('input:hidden[id $= "-id"]');
                var itemId = itemIdInput.val();
                var deleteInput = `<input type="hidden" name="line_items_to_delete" value="${itemId}">`;  // Update here....
                if( $(deleteInput).val() ) {
                  $('#line_items_to_delete').append(deleteInput);   // Update here....
                }

                var row = $(this).parents('.' + options.formCssClass),
                    del = row.find('input:hidden[id $= "-DELETE"]'),
                    buttonRow = row.siblings("a." + addCssSelector + ', .' + options.formCssClass + '-add'),
                    forms;
                if (del.length) {
                    del.val('on');
                    row.hide();
                    forms = $('.' + options.formCssClass);
                    totalForms.val(forms.length);
                } else {
                    row.remove();
                    forms = $('.' + options.formCssClass).not('.formset-custom-template');
                    totalForms.val(forms.length);
                }
                for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++) {
                    applyExtraClasses(forms.eq(i), i);
                    if (!del.length) {
                        forms.eq(i).find(childElementSelector).each(function() {
                            updateElementIndex($(this), options.prefix, i);
                        });
                    }
                }

                if (!showDeleteLinks()){
                    $('a.' + delCssSelector).each(function(){$(this).hide();});
                }
                if (buttonRow.is(':hidden') && showAddButton()) buttonRow.show();
                if (options.removed) options.removed(row);
                return false;
                }
              });
            };

        $$.each(function(i) {
            var row = $(this),
                del = row.find('input:checkbox[id $= "-DELETE"]');
            if (del.length) {
                if (del.is(':checked')) {
                    del.before('<input type="hidden" name="' + del.attr('name') +'" id="' + del.attr('id') +'" value="on" />');
                    row.hide();
                } else {
                    del.before('<input type="hidden" name="' + del.attr('name') +'" id="' + del.attr('id') +'" />');
                }
                $('label[for="' + del.attr('id') + '"]').hide();
                del.remove();
            }
            if (hasChildElements(row)) {
                row.addClass(options.formCssClass);
                if (row.is(':visible')) {
                    insertDeleteLink(row);
                    applyExtraClasses(row, i);
                }
            }
        });

        if ($$.length) {
            var hideAddButton = !showAddButton(),
                addButton, template;
            if (options.formTemplate) {
                template = (options.formTemplate instanceof $) ? options.formTemplate : $(options.formTemplate);
                template.removeAttr('id').addClass(options.formCssClass + ' formset-custom-template');
                template.find(childElementSelector).each(function() {
                    updateElementIndex($(this), options.prefix, '__prefix__');
                });
                insertDeleteLink(template);
            } else {
                if (options.hideLastAddForm) $('.' + options.formCssClass + ':last').hide();
                template = $('.' + options.formCssClass + ':last').clone(true).removeAttr('id');
                template.find('input:hidden[id $= "-DELETE"]').remove();
                template.find(childElementSelector).not(options.keepFieldValues).each(function() {
                    var elem = $(this);
                    if (elem.is('input:checkbox') || elem.is('input:radio')) {
                        elem.attr('checked', false);
                    }
                    if (elem.is('select')) {
                        elem.append('<option style="display:none" selected value="">Optional</option>');
                    }
                    else {
                        elem.val('');
                    }
                });
            }
            options.formTemplate = template;

            var addButtonHTML = '<a class="' + options.addCssClass + '" href="javascript:void(0)">' + options.addText + '</a>';
            if (options.addContainerClass) {
              var addContainer = $('[class*="' + options.addContainerClass + '"');
              addContainer.append(addButtonHTML);
              addButton = addContainer.find('[class="' + options.addCssClass + '"]');
            } else if ($$.is('TR')) {
                var numCols = $$.eq(0).children().length,
                    buttonRow = $('<tr><td colspan="' + numCols + '">' + addButtonHTML + '</tr>').addClass(options.formCssClass + '-add');
                $$.parent().append(buttonRow);
                addButton = buttonRow.find('a');
                UpdateFormSet();
            } else {
                $$.filter(':last').after(addButtonHTML);
                addButton = $$.filter(':last').next();
                UpdateFormSet();  
          }

            if (hideAddButton) addButton.hide();

            addButton.click(function() {
              var formCount = currentFormIndex,
                    row = options.formTemplate.clone(true).removeClass('formset-custom-template'),
                    buttonRow = $($(this).parents('tr.' + options.formCssClass + '-add').get(0) || this),
                    delCssSelector = $.trim(options.deleteCssClass).replace(/\s+/g, '.');

                    let highestId = 0;
                    const idRegex = /\d+/;
                    $("input[name$='-research_line_item_description']").each(function(){  // Update here....
                      const currentName = $(this).attr('name');
                      const idVal = currentName.match(idRegex);
                      const idInt = parseInt(idVal);
                      highestId = Math.max(highestId,parseInt(idInt));
                    });
                    formCount = highestId+1;

                applyExtraClasses(row, formCount);
                row.insertBefore(buttonRow).show();
                row.find(childElementSelector).each(function() {
                    updateElementIndex($(this), options.prefix, formCount);
                });
                totalForms.val(formCount + 1);
                if (showDeleteLinks()){
                  $('a.' + delCssSelector).each(function(){$(this).show();});
                  UpdateFormSet();
                 }
                if (!showAddButton()) buttonRow.hide();
                if (options.added) options.added(row);
                currentFormIndex++;
                return false;
            });
        }
        return $$;
    };

    /* Setup plugin defaults */
    $.fn.formset.defaults = {
        prefix: 'form',                         // The form prefix for your django formset
        formTemplate: null,                     // The jQuery selection cloned to generate new form instances
        addText: 'Add',                         // Text for the add link
        deleteText: 'Del',                      // Text for the delete link
        addContainerClass: null,                // Container CSS class for the add link
        deleteContainerClass: null,             // Container CSS class for the delete link
        addCssClass: 'add-row-budget',          // CSS class applied to the add link
        deleteCssClass: 'delete-row-budget',    // CSS class applied to the delete link
        formCssClass: 'dynamic-form',           // CSS class applied to each form in a formset
        extraClasses: [],                       // Additional CSS classes, which will be applied to each form in turn
        keepFieldValues: '',                    // jQuery selector for fields whose values should be kept when the form is cloned
        added: null,                            // Function called each time a new form is added
        removed: null,                          // Function called each time a form is deleted
        hideLastAddForm: false,                 // When set to true, hide last empty add form (becomes visible when clicking on add button)
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And then in my HTML....

```
<script>

function UpdateFormSet() {

  $(".add-row-budget").on('click', function() {
       UpdateTotals();
  });

}

</script>
```

I had to include several UpdateFormset() references but this solution ultimately worked.